# Есть два списка расположенные в две колонки. Количество элементов(li) в каждом списке разное

Tags: list, bootstrap4

Как сделать чтобы элементы каждого списка располагались друг против друга? 
На картинке красной линией я подчеркнул как должны быть расположены элементы. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<a href = "https://codepen.io/vvv7220/pen/GzjbER">Вот мой код, как не должно быть.</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://getbootstrap.ru/docs/v4-alpha/layout/grid/
[Тут есть пример с Cards](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#using-grid-markup)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6</div>
  <div class="col-md-6">col-md-6</div>
</div>
```

Готовое решение:

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
                        <b>1. Theorie</b>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Benötigtes Material</li>
                            <li>Arbeit mit Kunden und Pflegeempfehlungen</li>
                            <li>Fehlerkorrektur</li>
                        </ul>
    </div>  <div class="col-md-6">
                            <b>1. Theorie</b>
                        <ul>
                            <li>2-3D-Technik</li>
                            <li>Arbeitsstufen</li>
                            <li>Fehlerkorrektur</li>
                            <li>Arbeitsstufen</li>
                        </ul>
  </div></div> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
                        <b>2. Praktische Aufgabe</b>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Wimpernverlängerung am Modell</li>
                            <li>Einzel- oder Gruppentraining mit den Materialien der Schule.</li>
                            <li>Nach Abschluss des Kurses - ein internationaleres Zertifikat. </li>
                        </ul>
    </div>  <div class="col-md-6">
                            <b>2. Praktische Aufgabe</b>
                        <ul>
                            <li> Wimpernverlängerung am Modell</li>
                            <li>Wimpernkorrektur am Modell</li>
                            <li>Training nur für erfahrene Meister einzeln oder in einer Gruppe mit
                                den Materialien der Schule.</li>
                            <li>Nach Abschluss des Kurses - ein internationaleres Zertifikat.</li>
                        </ul>
    </div></div>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6"> 
                    <div class="kurs">
                        <span><a href="">KURS BUCHEN</a></span>
                    </div>

 </div>  
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="kurs">
                        <span><a href="">KURS BUCHEN</a></span>
                    </div>
  </div></div>
```

Comment: Смотри внимательно вопрос. В каждом списке разное количество элементов. Тем не менее они все находятся друг против друга. Подчеркнуты видишь, красной линией. То что ты мне дал, я давно знаю. Стоит добавить в одной карте несколько лишних строк и кнопка убегает вниз.

Comment: ну а кнопки в последний ров отдельно. что не так?

Comment: @vvv7220 Ты издеваешься? Ты подставить сам не можешь что ли?

Comment: То есть все что на одной линии помещать в отдельный raw? и заголовки тоже?

Comment: Вроде разобрался. Спасибо! Извиняюсь за мою тупость.